# PostgreSQL - How to dynamically execute a query in a function and return table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function, to which if I pass a variable then depending upon the value of the variable, different query should execute.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SW_Versions(VersionType varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(array_sw_version varchar) AS $$
BEGIN

IF VersionType = 'All' THEN

    EXECUTE 'select ''1'' as array1_sw_version UNION ALL
        select ''2'' as array1_sw_version';

ELSIF VersionType = 'Major' THEN

    EXECUTE 'select ''A'' as array2_sw_version UNION ALL
        select ''B'' as array2_sw_version';

ELSE
    EXECUTE 'select ''X'' as array3_sw_version UNION ALL
        select ''Y'' as array3_sw_version';
END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

SELECT SW_Versions('Major')
```

The above query is not yielding the correct result which should be 2.
Can anyone pls help me out in identifying what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is it not working?  Perhaps if you set up a SQL Fiddle, someone could help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Not sure why its not working..here is the output I am getting [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/rf3gX7v.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `EXECUTE`. Use `RETURN QUERY` instead. Casts (`::varchar`) added to provide column type compability.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SW_Versions(VersionType varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(array_sw_version varchar) AS $$
BEGIN

IF VersionType = 'All' THEN

    RETURN QUERY select '1'::varchar as array1_sw_version UNION ALL
        select '2'::varchar as array1_sw_version;

ELSIF VersionType = 'Major' THEN

    RETURN QUERY select 'A'::varchar as array2_sw_version UNION ALL
        select 'B'::varchar as array2_sw_version;

ELSE
    RETURN QUERY select 'X'::varchar as array3_sw_version UNION ALL
        select 'Y'::varchar as array3_sw_version;
END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;

SELECT SW_Versions('Major')
```